# checking if a value falls within a range of alphanumeric values

Tags: python

For this coding exercise I was supposed to take in a list of alphanumeric building codes and output json data with the corresponding code description information - relevant data is listed below my function. I know my solution is not good but I am kind of a noob and am not sure how I should have done this.

```
def return_code(code):
    """takes in a list of codes and returns a json dictionary of codes and corresponding      
    descriptions"""
     data = []
     for c in code:
         if c.startswith("M") and "R" in c:
              #gets mixed Res and Manufacturing districts

            data.append({"code": c, "description": "Mixed Manufacturing & Residential 
            Districts"})
        if c.startswith("M") and "R" not in c:
            data.append({"code": c, "description": "Manufacturing Districts"})
        if c.startswith("R"):
            data.append({"code": c, "description": "Residential Districts"})
        if c.startswith("ZR"):
            data.append({"code": c, "description": "Special Zoning District"})          
        if c == "ZNA":
            data.append({"code": c, "description": "Zoning Not Applicable"})
        if c == "BPC":
             data.append({"code": c, "description": "Battery Park City"})
        if c == "PARK":
            data.append({"code": c, "description": "New York City Parks"})
        if c == "PARKNYS":
            data.append({"code": c, "description": "New York State Parks"})
        if c == "PARKUS":
            data.append({"code": c, "description": "United States Parks"})
        if c.startswith("ZR"):
             data.append({"code": c, "description": "Special Zoning District"})
        else:
            pass
    return json.dumps(data)
```

As seen below, for example any code between R1-1 and R10H is 'Residential' but I am not sure of how I should check if a value falls between those alphanumeric values? I thought of using a dictionary of all codes with the corresponding info, but like in this case the formatting is different. R1-1 has the dash and R10H doesn't. What is the best way to check this?

---

```
Description Data:
Codes               Descriptions
---------------------------------------------------------------
R1-1 - R10H         Residential Districts
C1-6 - C8-4         Commercial Districts
M1-1 - M3-2         Manufacturing Districts
M1-1/R5 – M1-6/R10  Mixed Manufacturing & Residential Districts
BPC                 Battery Park City
PARK                New York City Parks
PARKNYS             New York State Parks
PARKUS              United States Parks
ZNA                 Zoning Not Applicable
ZR 11-151           Special Zoning District
```

Comment: When you say "any code between R1-1 and R10H", what are the codes in this range? If you know that, you can probably write a regex for it.

Comment: Split the string on the first dash/whitespace character - ie `re.split('\s|-',s)[0]`.  You can then do a simple dict lookup on everything but the `M1` strings - special-case those.

Comment: This problem seems to be more about domain specifics than about programming. They seem to work with a very loose definition of "range": What does `C1-6 - C8-4` mean for example? Would `C8-5` not fall in that range? It seems to me you need to dig up some more information on the exact specification of those ranges. Once you got that, regular expressions would probably be the right tool for the job.

Comment: In Section 11-122 of the article [Zoning Resolution - The City of New York](http://www.nyc.gov/html/dcp/pdf/zone/art01c01.pdf) there's an enumerated list of the possible zone codes. That might help you to get an idea of the range of values and build an appropriate regular expression.

Comment: Thank you all for clearing this up for me. I am a noob when it comes to regex so I need to brush up on that anyway, but it's good to at least have some direction now so I can improve.

Comment: @fromageball well, from what I can tell, the actual specifics of how the codes are defined don't seem to be too relevant for your problem. It's not like `C1-6 - C8-4` are "Commerical", but `C5-2` is something else entirely. So for your task, the definition `R1 + some random garbage` is close enough to identify "Residential Districts" ;-) The only exception is the pattern `M1-1/R5`. So I would suggest you [read up on regular expressions](http://regex101.com/#python) and build some for the patterns you need, and put them in a dictionary mapping them to the descriptions.

Comment: @fromageball to get you started: [this regex](http://regex101.com/r/sF4pZ0/1) for example *only* matches `M1-1` but not `M1-1/R5`, because it expects the "end of the line" marker (`$`) immediately after the second digit.

Comment: @Lukas thanks for the link! Going to practice now... I have worked with regex a bit in url management but not much else. So I am somewhat familiar with $, etc. That site is awesome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, this seems to be a job for regular expressions. The actual specifics of all the possible codes don't seem to matter too much for your task, you should be able to distingish most of them by looking at the start of the string.

I would suggest to define your regular expressions in a **dictionary** and map them to their respective descriptions. This should get you started:

```
import json
import re


PATTERNS = {
    '^R1??':      "Residential Districts",
    'C\d-\d':     "Commercial Districts",
    'M\d-\d$':    "Manufacturing Districts",
    'M1-\d/R\d*': "Mixed Manufacturing & Residential Districts",
    # ...
}


def return_code(codes):
    """takes in a list of codes and returns a json dictionary of codes
    and corresponding descriptions
    """
    descriptions = []
    for code in codes:
        for pattern, desc in PATTERNS.items():
            if re.match(pattern, code):
                descriptions.append({"code": code, "description": desc})
                # We found a matching pattern, no need to test the others
                break
        else:
            print "Code '%s' did not match any pattern!" % code
    return json.dumps(descriptions)

print return_code(['M1-1', 'ZNA'])
```

A couple notes:

- [`break`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) breaks out of the innermost `for` loop - in this case the loop that checks all the defined patterns against the current code. After we found one that matches, there's no point in checking any others.
- The [`else` clause of the `for` loop](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) is a bit special, it's something you don't see very often. The part in the `for..else` gets called if the loop terminated *normally*, which means it wasn't exited by a `break`. In our case that means that we went through all the patterns and none of them matched - so that could be an invalid building code, a missing pattern, an incorrect pattern, ...
- I intentionally left the trailing comma after the last entry in the `PATTERNS` dictionary. Python allows that, even though it's not necessary, and that's awesome. Because this means you can easily copy and paste lines to fill the rest of the patterns in, and move them up or down, without always having to remove / add commas.